# keep track of readfile() progress on server side

Tags: javascript, php

This is the PHP code I am using to allow users to download a file:

```
$path = "somepath"
header('Content-type: application');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($path);
```

Client js:

```
window.location = "/download";
```

I received bug reports that the download takes 20mins instead of seconds even on 100Mb/s network connection. I suspect a large portion of users cancels the download because of it, but I am not aware of the right logging tools. I am interested if it is possible to keep track of the download on the server side to see how often users experience slow download and keep a log of download times and how much of the file was downloaded?

Comment: You could start by logging the current time before and after the `readfile` call. But that only reads the file content and writes it to the output buffer, so that must not mean all data is send to the client already, once it returns from that call. Whether you will be able to determine how much of the file was downloaded, I don’t know - I guess that might rather require a solution that reads the file in smaller chunks, so that in combination with `ignore_user_abort` you could try and determine how much of it was already sent when the connection gets closed by the client.

Comment: can you give me some starting points for `a solution that reads the file in smaller chunks`?

Comment: https://zinoui.com/blog/download-large-files-with-php

Comment: The link @CBroe posted is probably exactly what you need. Reading in chunks and logging between chunks is the right approach in my opinion as well.

Comment: readfile() should perform equal-to-or-better-than fread() in every situation. If some users are getting slow downloads, but it IS downloading, then it's unlikely to be a code problem. First thing I would check is to see if you have any bandwidth-throttling mechanisms that might be impacting your site (e.g. shared hosting or cheap VPS). Also, turn on your browser's developer extensions (F12 key), switch to the network tab, and start a download and see what that looks like. If it takes a long time to start, maybe you're dealing with slow access to the source data. How big are the files?